# Unix Command to replace string in the line of searching pattern

Tags: unix

There is a file having the below data:

> stackover flow is using everyday stack has its own advantages.
>   There are many websites but it is the best
>   stackover flow is really awesome, stack of benefits.

I want to replace `stack` to --> `stackexchange` when any line having `stackover`.

Output should be like this :

> stackover flow is using everyday stackexchange has its own advantages.
>   There are many websites but it is the best
>   stackover flow is really awesome, stackexchange of benefits.

I tried with
`cat filename|grep 'stackover'|awk
 '{gsub("stack","stackexchange",$0);print}'`

but it is replacing `stackover` also. I dont want to correct the word which I am searching.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple ***sed*** approach:

Let's say we have a `testfile` with contents:

```
stackover flow is using everyday stack has its own advantages. There are many websites but it is the best stackover flow is really awesome, stack of benefits.
```

---

The command:

```
sed 's/\<stack\>/stackexchange/g' file
```

---

The output:

```
stackover flow is using everyday stackexchange has its own advantages. There are many websites but it is the best stackover flow is really awesome, stackexchange of benefits.
```

`\<` and `\>` - represent "word" boundaries

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the answer. Your suggestion is working for other scenarios where the replace string is different. Here it is not working,since both searching and replace string having same name STACK. Pls suggest if any alternatives.

Comment: @Srinivas, you should elaborate your question and add those different scenarios

Comment: My name is srinivas and srini. Imagine there are few lines of data like this. Iwant to grep srinivas from a file and in the line of srinivas if there is srini then replace it with cnu. My output should be --》my name is srinivas and cnu. But your command is giving answer as -->my name is cnuvas and cnu.

Comment: @Srinivas, I think you are wrong. Look at my answer again. I've added your input example and the output